# Android "skimlinks-unlinked"

Tags: android

In code examples I sometimes find lines like theses:

```
import <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">android.app.Activity</span>
import <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">android.os.Bundle</span>
```

I could not find anything on this in the documentation. Why is this used, what are the benefits?

Comment: Can you give a link to one of the code examples where you find lines like those?

Comment: "Why is this used" -- why is *what* used?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I think he/she is referring to the `<span class="skimlinks-unlinked"> </span>`.

Comment: Example: http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. This is actually a problem of Wordpress displaying code. It has nothing to do with Android (or any other programming language) and just has to be removed.

http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/skimlinks-messed-up-inside-code-tags-an-actual-error